# Morphia - Class not found defined in dbObj

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm having a rather interesting issue. When attempting to load a model from a Mongo instance, Morphia throws the following error:

```
[22:17:13 WARN]: Class not found defined in dbObj: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.mattrick.test.storage.TestStat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getClass(DefaultCreator.java:175) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:97) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readMapOrCollectionOrEntity(EmbeddedMapper.java:205) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:142) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:45) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:772) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:230) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:191) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:220) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.dao.BasicDAO.findOne(BasicDAO.java:180) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at me.mattrick.test.storage.UserRepository.getUserFromPlayer(UserRepository.java:22) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at me.mattrick.test.event.JoinEvent.onJoin(JoinEvent.java:37) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:298) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:157) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:144) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:54) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:231) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:148) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:814) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
[22:17:13 WARN]: Class not found defined in dbObj: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.mattrick.test.storage.TestStat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getClass(DefaultCreator.java:175) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:87) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:102) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readMapOrCollectionOrEntity(EmbeddedMapper.java:205) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:142) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:45) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:772) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:230) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:191) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:220) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.dao.BasicDAO.findOne(BasicDAO.java:180) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at me.mattrick.test.storage.UserRepository.getUserFromPlayer(UserRepository.java:22) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at me.mattrick.test.event.JoinEvent.onJoin(JoinEvent.java:37) [Test-1.5-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:298) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:157) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:144) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:54) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:231) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:148) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:814) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-e4d4710-e1ebe52]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
```

As you can see, I am running it inside a Spigot server (which is essentially a Minecraft server with a proper API implementation). I'm not sure if this is terribly relevant, but the Spigot server loads plugins in a similar way that Morphia would, so I think it may be possible that this is causing this issue, since there's been previous documented instances of Morphia conflicting with other libraries that use class loaders.

Adding "noClassnameStored = true" to the @Entity annotation seems to prevent this error, however I am storing a list of custom objects inside the database, which also causes this error.

The models I am using can be seen below:

Stat.java:

```
package me.mattrick.test.storage;

public class Stat {
}
```

TestStat.java:

```
package me.mattrick.test.storage;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class TestStat extends Stat {

    @Getter @Setter
    private int test = 100;

}
```

User.java:

```
package me.mattrick.test.storage;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import me.mattrick.test.Test;
import me.mattrick.test.api.storage.mongo.MongoEntity;
import me.mattrick.test.cosmetics.particles.EnumParticleEffect;
import me.mattrick.test.player.PlayerRank;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity(value = "users", noClassnameStored = true)
public class User extends MongoEntity {

    @Getter @Setter
    private UUID uuid;

    @Getter @Setter
    private PlayerRank rank = PlayerRank.DEFAULT;

    @Getter @Setter
    private EnumParticleEffect effect = EnumParticleEffect.NONE;

    @Getter @Setter
    private int money = 0;

    @Getter @Setter
    private int level = 0;

    @Getter @Setter
    private long experience = 0;

    @Getter @Setter
    private LocalDateTime firstJoined;

    @Getter @Setter
    private LocalDateTime lastPlayed;

    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Stat> stats = new ArrayList<>();

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid);
    }

    public void save() {
        Test.getInstance().getMongoBridge().repositoryBy(User.class).save(this);
    }

    public <T extends Stat> T getStat(Class<T> statClass) {
        for (Stat stat : stats) {
            if(stat.getClass() == statClass) {
                return statClass.cast(stat);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addStat(Stat stat) {
        stats.add(stat);
    }

}
```

MongoEntity.java:

```
package me.mattrick.test.api.storage.mongo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

public class MongoEntity {

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private ObjectId id;

}
```

It should be noted that the User class saves and loads fine as a result of the "noClassnameStored = true" parameter set on the @Entity annotation, but the Stat class does not, since this is not feasible for this.

Would anyone happen to know the solution to this? Its a rather odd error, and I'm not too experienced with Morphia. Thank you for you assistance and apologies for such a long post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out. You need to override Morphia's ClassLoader with your plugin's own. In case anyone using Spigot or Bukkit are looking for the answer:

```
morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setObjectFactory(new DefaultCreator() {
    @Override
    protected ClassLoader getClassLoaderForClass() {
        return JavaPlugin.getClassLoader();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who's coming across this issue (like I did) in 2020 and uses PaperSpigot, here's what I managed to do after resorting to Morphia's documentation. I am using [Morphia v1.6.0](https://morphia.dev/1.6.0/javadoc/) and [PaperSpigot 1.16.2](https://papermc.io/javadocs/paper/1.16/overview-summary.html).

```java
morphia.getMapper().setOptions(
    MapperOptions.legacy().classLoader(<MainClass>.class.getClassLoader())
        .build()
);
```

Here's an explanation:

1. The accepted answer shows that you can use [`.setObjectFactory`](https://morphia.dev/1.6.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html#setObjectFactory(dev.morphia.ObjectFactory)) to achieve this change. In my IDE (IntelliJ), it wasn't only marked as deprecated, but using that along with the [`DefaultCreator`](https://morphia.dev/1.6.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/DefaultCreator.html) wasn't doing the job. I don't think it's accepted practice in the new version(s) of Morphia? Anyways, I ended up using the [`setOptions`](https://morphia.dev/1.6.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/Mapper.html#setOptions(dev.morphia.mapping.MapperOptions)) method using the [legacy builder](https://morphia.dev/1.6.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html#legacy()) for setting [`MapperOptions`](https://morphia.dev/1.6.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html). This method wasn't deprecated either.
2. In the accepted answer, it shows the usage of [`JavaPlugin.getClassLoader()`](https://papermc.io/javadocs/paper/1.16/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html#getClassLoader--). That method is protected. Therefore you cannot access it directly. However, if you use your plugin's main class, for instance, you can access the `getClassLoader()` method with no issues. You're not going to want to directly access these methods unless you're trying to do some weird/hacky stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually stems from a broken classpath.  It would appear that you spigot server isn't including the jar with your entities on the classpath when it starts up.

Comment: Hmm, I am shading Morphia in with my plugin's JAR file, could that possibly be the cause of this? I can confirm that both of these models exist in the JAR file itself, but I'm not too sure why it is unable to instantiate them.

Comment: What's not being found is your entity not a morphia class.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a pain, but what would you suggest I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't know, really.  I don't know anything about spigot and it sounds like you have a lot of moving parts.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway :)