# Morphia - BasicDBObject cannot be cast to MyClass

Tags: java, mongodb, bukkit, morphia

I am trying to embed a hashmap into my MongoDB using Morphia. After the same warning as the post here:

[Morphia - Class not found defined in dbObj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822116/morphia-class-not-found-defined-in-dbobj/38841585#38841585)
Note: Just to be thorough here, suggestions in this post DID NOT help.

I was finally able to figure out that if I added a @Property attribute to my embedded field, it would suppress the warning.

Unfortunately this now leads to the problem where instead of having an array of my hashmap object, I seem have an array of BasicDBObject that I'm unable to cast back to my hashmap type

The answers on the mentioned post also suggest overriding morphia's class loader. Unfortunately the getter they used in their example is now protected, thus I am now unable to return JavaPlugin.getClassLoader()

Full error:

```java
[23:29:01 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'quest' in plugin ExploreRPG v1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:739) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1800) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1608) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:47) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:5) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$ensureMainThread$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:23) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:136) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:109) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.aX(MinecraftServer.java:1013) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:1006) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(IAsyncTaskHandler.java:119) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:990) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:923) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to net.exploremc.explorerpg.controllers.user.QuestProgress
        at net.exploremc.explorerpg.controllers.User.getActiveQuests(User.java:148) ~[?:?]
        at net.exploremc.explorerpg.commands.QuestCMD.onCommand(QuestCMD.java:23) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched_1.14.4.jar:git-Paper-176]
        ... 17 more
```

User class:

```java
@Entity(value = "users", noClassnameStored = true)
public class User {
    @Transient public static HashMap<UUID, User> usersList = new HashMap<>();
    @Transient private static Datastore datastore = ExploreRPG.getDatabase().getDatastore();

    @Id private String id;
    @Transient private Player player;
    @Indexed private String uuid;

    private List<String> ipHistory = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> nameHistory = new ArrayList<>();
    @Embedded @Property("quests") private HashMap<String, QuestProgress> quests = new HashMap<>();    // This is the problem class

    public User(){ }

    public User(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.ipHistory.add(player.getAddress().getHostString());
        this.uuid = player.getUniqueId().toString();
        this.nameHistory.add(player.getName());
    }

    public void storeUser() {
        datastore.save(this);
    }

    public void updateUser(){
        Query<User> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(User.class).field("uuid").equal(uuid);
        UpdateOperations<User> ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(User.class)
                .set("ipHistory", ipHistory)
                .set("nameHistory", nameHistory)
                .set("quests", quests);
        datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
    }

    public static boolean doesUserExist(Player player){

        Query<User> query = datastore.find(User.class).field("uuid").equal(player.getUniqueId().toString());
        User user = query.first();
        return user != null;
    }

    public static User getUserFromDB(Player player){
        Query<User> query = datastore.find(User.class).field("uuid").equal(player.getUniqueId().toString());
        User user = query.first();
        user.quests = query.first().quests;
        user.player = player;
        return user;
    }
}
```

Implementation that causes this error:

```
public List<QuestProgress> getActiveQuests(){
        List<QuestProgress> activeQuests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (QuestProgress quest : quests.values()) {
            if(!quest.isCompleted())
                activeQuests.add(quest);
        }
        return activeQuests;
    }
```

I expect to be able to loop through the `quest` hashmap, however the program fails the moment it gets to the foreach loop.
Inspecting the data class, shows that the map data is not as expected. Instead the value is of BasicDBObject type, and I believe this is what is causing my error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3herm.png

I have tried to recast this new structure into my original map without luck.

I am using Morphia core 1.5.3
mongo-java-driver version 3.11.0
Working with Spigot 1.14.4 API

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `map()` explicitly on that type?  Morphia can do some deferred mapping but it's possible this is a code path where that is broken.